# Create new columns based on another column value

Tags: pandas

Assuming I have the following toy dataset:

```
count    orders    books  
   1         40       2 
   1         60       4
   1         80       6
   2         10       8
   2         30      10
   2         50      12
```

I want to create new columns by transforming the dataset such that each column only contains `orders` and `books` by the `count` group

This is the output:

```
   orders_1   orders_2    books_1    books_2  
       40           10        2           8
       60           30        4          10
       80           50        6          12
```

I have attempted to use pivot tables, but the code throws me an error for using the same `index` as well as `columns`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, pivot by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and last flatten `MultiIndex in columns`:

```
df = df.assign(g = df.groupby('count').cumcount()).pivot('g','count')
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
print (df)
   orders_1  orders_2  books_1  books_2
g                                      
0        40        10        2        8
1        60        30        4       10
2        80        50        6       12
```